# how to disable scroll sign near mouse pointer

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, windows-11

this sign is near pointer and disables scrolling on browsers. can you help me about it?[image]

Comment: If this is a laptop, try pinching on the touchpad with two fingers (in or out).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey its a touchpad but im using mouse and keyboard and pinching only changed the zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn off the "4-Way Wheel" setting or select "Normal Mouse Wheel" if you're using a mouse that comes with dedicated software, like the wireless A4Tech mouse I'm using. Right-click on the mouse software icon on the taskbar to find this option.